# Is there a way to integrate swagger-ui into a Play 2.4 project?

Tags: playframework, swagger, swagger-ui, playframework-2.4

I was able to integrate swagger-json support into my Play 2.4 project using https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play. And also I managed to create swagger-ui for the generated swagger-json with another self-hosted repo using https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui.

Is there a way to integrate swagger-ui into Play 2.4 project without another self hosted repo? I tried with [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) but the wordnik library it is using breaks with Play 2.4. Are there any other available swagger-ui projects or any other workaround?

Comment: Simply copy the folder `swagger-ui/dist` into your play app `public/` directory and add the appropriate route.

Comment: The problem is the wordnik-swagger library which needs to run the swagger-ui still breaks with play 2.4 version.